# sectionlinesformat to include indent also

Tags: koma-script

Please check the following `mwe`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}

\colorlet{sectioncolor}{blue}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \colorbox{sectioncolor}{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
      \raggedsection\color{white}\@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello
          \subsection{Foo}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Which yields the output as
[image]

But This is not what I am looking for. I am trying to achieve the background color should be aligned in right hand side, e.g.

```
|----------------------------------|
|1 Hello___________________________|
    * Hello
    |------------------------------|
    | 1.1 Foo______________________|
```

Comment: Why is there a `\subsection` inside of an `itemize` environment? Probably yome background information on that would be useful.

Comment: The `\subsection`  is inside itemize only to get the similar background. If I can get the background using something else, I will be happy to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `\textwidth` with `\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}

\colorlet{sectioncolor}{blue}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \colorbox{sectioncolor}{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
      \raggedsection\color{white}\@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Hello}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello \colorlet{sectioncolor}{Lavender!60}
          \subsection{Foo}
\end{itemize}
          \subsection{FooFoo}

\end{document}
```

[image]